# Gradle rmp build from java multiproject

Tags: java, gradle, multi-project

I am trying to build an RPM Centos 7 package from java source via Gradle. 
I have a java multi project environment with a shared library and a Java application.
Here is the filesystem:

```
|-- automation
build.gradle
settings.gradle
    |-- datalib
        |-- build
            |-- libs
            datalib-1.0.jar
        |-- src
            |-- main
                |-- it
                    |-- datalib
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    |-- metrics   
        |-- build
            |-- distributions
            metrics-1.0.rpm
        |-- libs
        metrics-1.0.jar
        |-- src
            |-- main
                |-- it
                    |-- metrics
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

The automation `settings.gradle` is:

```java
rootProject.name = 'automation'
include 'metrics' 
include 'datalib'
```

the automation `build.gradle` is:

```java
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.11
    targetCompatibility = 1.11

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    version = '1.0'


    dependencies {
        implementation group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.1'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

}

project(':metrics'){
    dependencies{
        implementation project(':datalib')
    }
}
```

I would like to build the RPM from the `metrics` project including the `datalib` library in the RPM.
I have written this Gradle `build.gradle` file but it doesn't work:

```java
// apply plugin: 'application'

plugins {
    id "application"
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "8.3.0"
    id 'com.palantir.git-version' version '0.12.3'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.6'
}

ospackage {
        def details = versionDetails()
        packageName = 'metrics'
        license = 'Proprietary Software'
        description = 'Events Analytics Software'
        version = details.lastTag
        release = details.commitDistance + 1 + '.' + details.gitHash
        arch = X86_64
        os = LINUX
        type = BINARY
        user 'root'
        fileMode 0644
        requires('java', '1.9', GREATER | EQUAL)
        vendor 'xxx'
        directory('/etc/metrics', 755)
        from(jar.outputs.files) {
            into '/usr/share/metrics'
        }
        from(':datalib:/build/libs') {
            into '/usr/share/metrics'
        }
}


// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'it.fox.metrics.App'
```

The RPM I have doesn't contain the `datalib` library

```sh
MacBook-Pro:distributions fox$ rpm -qlp metrics-1.0~471-262.f5ad4a18ca.x86_64.rpm
/usr/share/metrics
/usr/share/metrics/metrics-1.0.jar
```

How could I include my shared library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. 
I post the solution here, maybe could help someone. 
The solution was to use a Gradle `configurations` api. 
My Gradle configuration became:

```java
// apply plugin: 'application'

plugins {
    id "application"
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "8.3.0"
    id 'com.palantir.git-version' version '0.12.3'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.6'
}

ospackage {
        def details = versionDetails()
        packageName = 'metrics'
        license = 'Proprietary Software'
        description = 'Events Analytics Software'
        version = details.lastTag
        release = details.commitDistance + 1 + '.' + details.gitHash
        arch = X86_64
        os = LINUX
        type = BINARY
        user 'root'
        fileMode 0644
        requires('java', '1.9', GREATER | EQUAL)
        vendor 'xxx'
        directory('/etc/metrics', 755)
        from(configurations.runtimeClasspath) {
            into '/usr/share/metrics'
        }
}
```

Hope this could help someone.